# Bulk insert csv - column value itself has commas

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

The Activity column has values that have commas in the text

Some records in the csv :

```
Name,Project,Activity,Hrs
John,,,7.1
,Junkie,,7.1
,,Reviewing the,file,7.1 //This is under 'Activity' column and it has a comma in the text
```

When I use the bulk insert, i get 'bulk load data conversion for this line. If this line is removed or the comma in that sentence is removed, it works all good.

Please let me know what are the options in this case. I have many csv files, and each might have many such values.

Comment: If the field with the comma is not properly quoted, then it's not a valid CSV file in the first place.

Comment: @Pointy according to the definition, it is.

Comment: Is it possible to recreate the files using a different separator, such as `;` or even `|`?

Comment: None of the values are Quoted. it's just as it is, I have put in the Question

Comment: @ignaces what "definition"?  Without a mechanism for quoting field separators, it's impossible to unambiguously parse the file contents.

Comment: If the content arrives from Some Outside Source such that the source creation mechanisms cannot be changed, another option you have is to forcibly insert quotation or change the separator character yourself with a script.  Consider a regexp like `/^([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*),([^,]*)$/\"$1\",\"$2\",\"$3\",\"$4\"/` if your file is guaranteed to have no other columns with this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had this particular issue and the creation of the CSV files was not under my control, I would resort to a Perl script like this:

```
open(my $fhin, "<", "MyFile.csv");
open(my $fhout, ">", "MyQFile.csv");

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
  chomp($line);
  $line =~ s/^([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*),([^,]*)$/\"$1\",\"$2\",\"$3\",\"$4\"/;

  print $fhout $line . "\n";
}
```

Note that the above regular expression can handle only one "problem" column of this kind.  If there are any others, there is no possibility of programmatically assigning correct quotation to such columns (without more information...).

Comment: If the "problem column" is not the second-to-last column, won't the greedy `(.*)` consume too much of the line?

Comment: @Pointy: I'm not sure what you mean; I specified "non-comma" followed by "comma" for each of the non-problem columns and I specified beginning and end of line, this should mean that there are at least three commas in a match, and that at least three of the capture groups cannot have commas inside them.  Is there a case you see that breaks this?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean - the explicit commas would force the regex to backrack. OK then :)

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue where a text string had a comma in the string.  I used the following field terminator to resolve.

FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'

This does not work on CSV and I had to save my files as .txt.

Comment: So you suggest moving the problem (now texts with tabs will cause problems) instead of fixing it?